# get unique matches

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I get unique matches played between two teams

```
Game_Number, Team_A, Team_B, Date, Team_A_score, Team_B_score
1, IND, USA, 2020-01-01, 10, 20
2, USA, IND, 2020-01-02, 10, 20
3, AUS, IND, 2020-01-02, 30, 15
4, IND, AUS, 2020-01-03, 22, 34
5, UAE, AUS, 2020-01-04, 14, 41
```

Expected output

```
IND, USA
AUS, IND
UAE, AUS
```

In above case 1 and 2 games will be considered unique

Comment: By writing some SQL code to start with. Please, show **your** attempt and describe what is wrong with it. And describe the rules to mark games as "unique"

Comment: What is the logic behind deciding that a pair of matches are unique? In 1 and 2, the team names are swapped but the scores are not swapped and the dates are different so why is that "unique"?

Comment: It was interview question to me, but I did grouping of teams..and that didnt work and couldnt think of anything else that time

Comment: Was there an expected result?

Comment: @MT0, need to find only unique matches happened, neglect all remaining attributes.

Comment: @FreshTransistor That does not answer the question. What is the logic behind deciding that a pair of matches are unique?

Comment: @MT0, just a interview question, what else I can say

Comment: @RadimBača, updated in question

Comment: "and that didnt work" - please, **never**, exactly never use this general phrase about something that doesn't meet your needs. We cannot read your mind to identify what is wrong. Maybe the DB server was shut down, it is also "doesn't work"

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind the order of the teams then use `DISTINCT` with `GREATEST` and `LEAST`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       LEAST(Team_A, Team_B) AS team_a,
       GREATEST(Team_A, Team_B) AS team_b
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Game_Number, Team_A, Team_B, "DATE", Team_A_score, Team_B_score) AS
SELECT 1, 'IND', 'USA', DATE '2020-01-01', 10, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'USA', 'IND', DATE '2020-01-02', 10, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'AUS', 'IND', DATE '2020-01-02', 30, 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'IND', 'AUS', DATE '2020-01-03', 22, 34 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'UAE', 'AUS', DATE '2020-01-04', 14, 41 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | TEAM_A | TEAM_B |
> | --- | --- |
> | IND | USA |
> | AUS | IND |
> | AUS | UAE |

---

If you want to respect the order of the teams and get the earliest instance of a pairing of teams then:

```sql
SELECT Team_A,
       Team_B
FROM   (
  SELECT Team_A,
         Team_B,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY LEAST(Team_A, Team_B), GREATEST(Team_A, Team_B)
           ORDER BY "DATE"
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which outputs:

> | TEAM_A | TEAM_B |
> | --- | --- |
> | AUS | IND |
> | UAE | AUS |
> | IND | USA |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a18120f01d4c9fbc62a83a30fe7e50ff)*

Comment: its a direct function :) but if anyone dont remember this function and want to solve without it..any other way..?

Comment: You can use a `CASE` expression instead of `GREATEST` or `LEAST`.